# Configuration Error on web host ,Could not load file or assembly

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012

Please i want to solve this problem i did .aspx web application and when i try to publish it by GearHost i face this problem

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:


An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Source File: C:\home\site\wwwroot\web.config    Line: 14

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3429.0
```

and my web.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=8.0.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Please can anyone help me

Comment: Verify if the referenced dll version and version mentioned in web config are matching. Also see if dll is available in bin folder after build

Comment: The message says (a few times) that MySQL.Data.dll is missing (on the server).  Take a look on your server, in the `bin` folder.  Is that file is missing?  Get a copy from your dev machine.

Comment: Thank you every body i see that no bin folder in web application i will  create it and try again .
@RajeshG 
tgolisch